# Button not showing on phone but yes on XCode simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I've created a popup `UIView` that is a subview of my main view and a `UIButton` that is a close button that is a subview of my main view.

As shown in the picture the button shows in the `XCode` `iPhone simulator` in my `Mac` but when I test it in the physical phone the ICON/Button is not showing.

Why is not showing on my actuall phone but yes on the simulator? I've no errors, not even in the Phone console.... I have no idea how to debug this.

```
- (void) addCloseButton:(UIView*)myView {
    CGRect position = CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x - 20, myView.frame.origin.y -20, 40, 40);

    UIButton* myCloseButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:position];
    [myCloseButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    myCloseButton.tag = 45;
    [myCloseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(removePopup)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:myCloseButton];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check your image resource name, is "close" or "Close", the device is case sensitive and the simulator is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try tapping where the button *should* be. If that works as intended, it is probably just a problem loading the asset.

The simulator is case-insensitive, devices are not.

Comment: Thanks, Making the first latter worked eventhough the file is in lower case :S